# Want to compute product of Bessel and Hankel function in Matlab - $J_m(x)\cdot H_m^{(1)}(y)$ - but large order or argument returns 'inf'?

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, matlab, computational-mathematics, bessel-functions

I am trying to compute (in Matlab) the product of a Bessel function and a Hankel function where the order $m$ of the functions may be very large and/or the arguments $\alpha x$ and $\alpha y$ of the functions are complex and of large magnitude. Note that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers of order $1$ and it is the $\alpha$ that can be complex and of large magnitude. So I am looking to compute $u_m$ defined by

$$
u_m(x,y) = J_m(\alpha x) \cdot H_m^{(1)}(\alpha y).
$$

- When the order $m$ is large enough, Matlab returns `inf` for $H_m^{(1)}(\alpha y)$
- When the complex argument $\alpha x$ is large enough, Matlab returns `inf` for $J_m(\alpha x)$

However, when one of the functions is very large the other one is always very very small so that $u_m$ is in fact always some small number, e.g. $u_m$ ranges from around $O(10^{-4})$ down to zero.

But even though $u_m$ always exists and is small, I can't compute it because of the value `inf` for either $H_m^{(1)}(\alpha y)$ or $J_m(\alpha x)$. Is there some way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Seems to be two types of functions referred to as Hankel http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelFunction.html which ones are you interested in?

Comment: Could you please provide a code example with some numbers?

Comment: One thing that's easy to do is to use an asymptotic approximation when $m$ is large and $x$ and $y$ are fixed. Then $u_m(x, y) \sim x^m y^{-m}/(\pi m i)$. If $x$ is large and $m$ and $y$ are fixed, the second factor can't balance the first factor; is there an additional relation for $x$ and $y$? Also, is $m$ an integer?

Comment: @Maxim That identity seems to work pretty well, did you derive from the asymptotic expansion of bessel functions for high order? Regarding $x$ large and $m$ and $y$ fixed, I made a slight error in my question when I was trying to simplify it. I have now corrected the question. As you can see $\alpha$ is common to both terms.

Comment: @mathreadler I am considering the cylindrical Hankel functions of the first kind of order $m$.

Comment: Right, that just comes from applying the first two formulas from [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.19). If $x, y, m$ are fixed, we can get the approximation
$$\frac {e^{i y \alpha} (e^{-i x \alpha} - i e^{i (x \alpha - \pi m)})}
 {\pi \sqrt {x \alpha} \sqrt {y \alpha}}$$
(not an asymptotic equivalence because of the oscillatory terms). But this is a good approximation only if $\arg(x \alpha)$ and $\arg(y \alpha)$ do not approach $\pm \pi$. Also, the exponents can become positive, so $u_m$ does not in fact stay bounded.